# Accessing go env variables from within a Go program

Tags: go

I recently had a requirement to install [golangci-lint](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/install/#other-ci) via Go program itself. I am using the [exec package](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec) for creating `shell` and `go env` sub-processes.

However, I would like to improve by using some Go package for accessing the Go specific env variables rather calling out to `go env` as a separate process. Is there a builtin or third-party package for the job?

Comment: *"Does Go provide some package to examine its own runtime?"* -- Yes, and the package is called [`runtime`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime@go1.17.5). And also note that `go env` does NOT provide access to Go's *runtime* environment.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for pointing out the runtime package. However towards the end of https://pkg.go.dev/runtime@go1.17.5#hdr-Environment_Variables section it says 'the values are baked at compile time' plus I see GOROOT but can't see how I would access GOPATH/GOBIN via that package. I am editing my question to be more specifc about GO env vars

Comment: You can easily reverse engineer `go env` yourself. It is very straightforward and there are some reflect/linker tricks to get to the "internal" symbols if you really feel like it. Start here: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/envcmd/env.go